# Getting value from session PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables, sessionid

I am not sure why the variable username is not being returned in the session.  When the user logs in, I start the session:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
$_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;
```

On the user's welcome page, when I run the echo command, I see the proper variable being returned.  But I'm not sure why the return statement isn't working.  I have the following in my PHP file:

```
function UserName()
{

    return  isset($_SESSION['name_of_user']) ? $_SESSION['name_of_user'] : "Unknown User" ;
    //echo $_SESSION['name_of_user'];
}
```

In my html, I have:

```
Welcome back <?PHP $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>!
```

I also checked the session ID, and it's also being generated properly.
Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: forgot echo `<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `fgmembersite` an object and have it the function called `UserName` ?

If yes, you simply miss an `echo`

```
<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add echo or print so should look like this;

```
<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out your variable. Use

`Echo` or `print`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you should add output:

```
<?php print $fgmembersite->UserName(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the script I think you are using, you need to look through fg_membersite.php at the line that says:

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
```

whithin that line you should have a MySQL statement:

```
$qry = "SELECT etc...
```

When I tried to add UserAvatar I was able to do that by adding it to that MySQL string.

On a side note, I too am having trouble with adding UserName, and for the life of me I can't figure out why it would work any different than my previous workaround, yet somehow it is, but I am still convinced something in that file will do the trick eventually.

Edited:

Ok i got it, just do this:

echo $fgmembersite->UserName($username);

The username will pop right out. I have no idea why, i don't know enough php to explain it, but i can only assume this will get you going.